# How to fix update list item fields properties values without creating a new version

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

using Microsoft Graph API to update a Sharepoint 365 list item fields metadata (e.g. document library list item), the item version number is incremented to the next one.

Moreover, this update takes a while (a couple of seconds), and I suspect this is due to the time the system needs to create the new version data.

We also observed that Powershell Sharepoint PNP API commands have the option to call with the "UpdateOverwriteVersion" setting, that makes exactly what we are looking to do with Microsoft Graph API.

We previously made this same question in the GitHub Microsoft API Doc project, where we were adviced to ask in Stackoverflow in order to resolve this faster.

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/4909

Example of updating an item in Sharepoint 365 using Microsoft Graph API:

```
 PATCH /sites/[site-id]/lists/[list-id]/items/[item-id]/fields
```

JSON body data:

```
{
"OneDummyField": "Example data"
}
```

Anyway to make the update without incrementing the version?

Thank you very much. Best regards

Answer (score 2):

You can't, it's the way SharePoint is designed (for online anyways, with on prem you can I think). Everytime you make a change the etag is incremented.

Comment: You can do a SystemUpdate() with SharePoint online too, via CSOM, which is a relatively recent addition. But you can't do it via Graph.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSOM to solve this:

```
const ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

const list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('My list');
const item = list.getItemById(1);

item.set_item('Title', `Updated with JSOM request, ${new Date().toISOString()}`);
// item.update(); // -> creates new version, updates Editor and modified date
// item.updateOverwriteVersion(); // -> creates no new version, updates Editor and modified date
item.systemUpdate(); // -> creates no new version, Editor and modified date remains untouched

ctx.executeQuery(success, failure);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.